# How to create a web graph for URL's?

Tags: java, semantic-web

I am developing a java project in which i collect hyperlinks from a given input url and crawl those collected hyperlinks to collect more webpages related to the first given input url. After collecting, i need to form a web graph (like the image shown below) showing relations from one page to another. How can i do it in java.?

for eg- http://uploading.com/files/get/2d51d3fb/untitled.JPG

Answer (score 0):

You can find some resources on graph drawing here:  http://www.graphviz.org/Resources.php

I'm not sure if any of them are Java-specific, but it might get you headed in the right direction.  There's also the possibility of interfacing with Graphvis itself.  You can just build simple text files representing the edges in your graph (directed or undirected), then feed them to the tools and have them generate images.  That's kind of an ugly solution, but it might be good enough depending on what you need this for.

Comment: "You can just build simple text files representing the edges in your graph (directed or undirected), then feed them to the tools and have them generate images". This has to be done through graphviz or some other method.?

Comment: You build the text files yourself, then call one of the graphviz tools from the command line to create the image.  Here is a tutorial:  http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7275

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am now learning the tutorial. Will try it out and reply.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard.  The files are just text files containing something like digraph { A -> B  B -> C } or graph { A -- B B -- C } depending on whether they're directed graphs or not and most of the options on the tools are there to specify what sort of output you want.